# Some device constantly detaches and attaches on windows 7

Tags: windows, device, external-connection

I have a problem - on the Workstation, every 2-10 minutes you can hear a tone "device detached", and the UI freeses for a few seconds (1-2 seconds no mouse move, etc). It is a workstation with lots of external stuff (about 20 different USB and SATA devices) attached. Sounds like a fauly cable or bad contact somewhere, or maybe a defective external drive, hardware programmer, or similar.... How can I find out, which device is at fault? Any possibility to log the device activity?

Comment: Maybe `c:\windows\inf\setupapi.dev.log` ?  (Failing that, process of elimination: start by unplugging half the devices, and waiting 30 minutes or until the error occurs.  That can be tricky, though, the fault might be in a hub or USB controller rather than one of the external devices.)

Comment: Hmm, I removed every external device by now, except the hard drive which is now heavily in use for 3D processing. It cant be at fault as it would cause a renderer to fail... Looks like some internal thing - my workstation is about 7 years old (and is still close to the top of performance.... at a cost of power consumption I suppose...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you leave device manager open and reresh it when you hear the noise you may be able to see what is disconnected.  By "all devices"  I assume you also pulled the mouse keyboard?  In my experience it is usually these that flake out.  Also sometimes folks bump data cables, or a connection is loose or fails from repeated plugging/unplugging.

Could also be the drive getting weird, check the windows system log and it should also give you an error.  If it is a squirrely device a firmware update might fix it.

Also make sure it's not something dumb like someone leaving outlook open and changed the notification sound.

Comment: Dang, I did not thought about the mouse. Checked everything except it, just to find out that a 3 weeks old mouse causes that. Replaced with a cheap spare which I had for RasPi development, and not a single problem since....